# Command /usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, hudson

I am using Hudson Continuous Integration for first time with my iOS project and while building the project I am getting following error.

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
lipo -create /Users/test/.hudson/jobs/eDetails/workspace/build/eDetail.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSSDetail.build/Objects-normal/i386/SSSDetail /Users/test/.hudson/jobs/eDetails/workspace/build/SSSDetail.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSSDetail.build/Objects-normal/i386/SSSDetail -output /Users/test/.hudson/jobs/eDetails/workspace/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSSDetail.app/eDetail

/usr/bin/lipo: /Users/test/.hudson/jobs/eDetails/workspace/build/SSSDetail.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSSDetail.build/Objects-normal/i386/SSSDetail and /Users/test/.hudson/jobs/eDetails/workspace/build/SSSDetail.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSSDetail.build/Objects-normal/i386/SSSDetail have the same architectures (i386) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

Command /usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1

Do anybody have some idea, how can I sort out this problem??

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked

In target->build settings->valid architectures

Changing the value from "armv7 armv7s" to "armv7s"

I have iOS Deployment Target 4.3.

Encountered while converting to Objective-C ARC in XCode Version 4.6 (4H127)

Comment: I already had tried this solution from other answers on forum but didn't work for me. My deployment target is iOS 5.0